# How to add a DLL to a C# program in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, dll

I have a DLL (not a NuGet package) I want to reference in a C# program, in Visual Studio Code (not Visual Studio) V1.52.1. I cannot seem to add the reference.

The DLL is named Plumage.dll. The source code line looks like this:

```
Plumage.TSDRReq t = new Plumage.TSDRReq();
```

That generates the error "The type or namespace name 'Plumage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [testplum]csharp(CS0246)"

Adding

```
Using Plumage;
```

does not help and generates the same error message for that line.

I have tried copying the dll to: the same directory as my source; to the subdirectories `obj\Debug\net5.0` and `obj\Debug\net5.0\ref`; and to the subdirectories `bin\Debug\net5.0` and `bin\Debug\net5.0\ref`.

I have tried adding different variations of the following to my .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="Plumage.dll">
    <HintPath>Plumage.dll</HintPath>
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion> 
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I am running `dotnet restore` (and/or `dotnet restore force`) after changes. Still no progress.

I've read and tried the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43819808/cant-reference-dll-assembly-to-the-visual-studio-code-project) (but that's to add a project, not a dll) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46815546/how-to-add-external-assembly-dll-to-net-core-2-0-on-visual-studio-code) .

I'm finding a lot of information on how to add a NuGet package (but this is not a NuGet package); and a lot of information adding a reference using Visual Studio (but this is Visual Studio **Code**); but I'm still stuck.

Comment: is there a specific reason why you use ```VS Code```  for that instead ```VS``` ?

Comment: @Tomek: One possible reason would be that .NET 5 and Visual Studio Code run on Linux and Visual Studio doesn't.

Comment: You are missing a "using" statment at top of module.  To find the namespace (like System.Data) in Solution Explorer under reference right click and selct properties.  The namespace will be in the properties.

Comment: @BenVoigt that's why I am asking if there is a reason not to use VS ..

Comment: @jdweng: No `using` statement is needed when using qualified names, as the example line of code does.  But the compiler will need a `/reference` parameter, which should be setup through the project file.

Comment: the path to Plumage.dll is probably wrong. You probably need some of these guys, "..\",  to get the correct relative path

Comment: Aha, thank you, @Shanie, that was the problem. At least with a fully-qualified pathname it's found. I can play around and see what relative paths work now. I'm on to new problems now, but at least I can move forward.

Comment: @codingatty Cool, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

The `Include` attribute in the `Reference` tag isn't supposed to have the `.dll` extension.  It's not a filename.

You can see examples in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16580870/103167
and in this question: [Which one is correct approach for assembly reference in csproj file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11108838/103167)